# pySerial can send data time to arduino

Tags: python, arduino

I am trying to send date time to arduino using Python with serial communication, but I am having trouble sending the data. When I use `var = raw_input ("input:")` 
the data is sent. However when I use `var = str (time.asctime (time.localtime (time.time ())))` the data not sent to arduino.

Here's my Python code:

```
import serial, time

port = serial.Serial('COM4',9600)
var = str(time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time())))
if port.isOpen():
   print ('Port Aktif')
   while 1:
       port.write(var)
       time.sleep(1)
       print port.readline()
else:
   print 'port Tidak Aktif'
```

my code arduino :

```
String msg ="";
void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600); // set the baud rate

}
void loop() {
   if(Serial.available() > 0){
      while (Serial.available()>0){
         msg += char(Serial.read());
         delay(30);
      }
      Serial.println(msg);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#classes

it says:

```
write(data)
[...]
Write the bytes data to the port.
This should be of type bytes (or compatible such as bytearray or memoryview). 
Unicode strings must be encoded (e.g. 'hello'.encode('utf-8').
```

This means, use

```
var = bytes(time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time())).encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: I try your suggestion to use this code var = bytes(time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time())).encode('utf-8')). But still the same. i use Python2.7

Comment: what does a print type(var) say for var = raw_input ("input:") and for var = bytes(time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time())).encode('utf-8'))? It will have someting to do with the difference between str and bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
In [1]: import time

In [2]: str(time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time())))
Out[2]: 'Sat May  6 14:39:17 2017'
```

use:

```
In [3]: time.asctime(time.localtime()).encode('utf-8')
Out[3]: b'Sat May  6 14:39:17 2017'
```

The latter will return a string of bytes, which is required when writing to a serial port.

Comment: i try time.asctime(time.localtime()).encode('utf-8') or str(time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))) The results are still the same, I am confused what is wrong with my code